# How to dynamically import non-React client side libraries in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, abcjs

I have a simple project

```
import Music from '../components/music';
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Music></Music>
  )
}
```

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const abcjs = dynamic(import('abcjs'), { ssr: false });

export default function Music({note}) {
    return (
        <>
            <div id="paper"></div>
            {abcjs.renderAbc("paper", "X:1\nK:D\nDDAA|BBA2|\n")}
        </>
    )
}
```

my `package.json` is

```
{
  "name": "music-quiz",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "abcjs": "^5.12.0",
    "next": "10.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

However, the browser tells me `abcjs.renderAbc is not a function` and as far as I can tell this should work.

If it makes any difference I'm running `next.js` with `npm run dev`.

If I try to log abcjs I appear to get sort of an empty object. `vscode` tells me that there is it cannot find a declaration type for `abcjs`, but that shouldn't matter.

Clearly the library isn't being imported correctly but I have no idea why this is.

EDIT: I should add that I found this [example](https://paulrosen.github.io/abcjs/overview/getting-started.html#which-flavor-should-you-use) and are adapting it to `next`.

There is also something in the [FAQ](https://paulrosen.github.io/abcjs/overview/faq.html#can-i-use-abcjs-in-react-native-other-mobile-development-frameworks) about this, but it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: `next/dynamic` is used to dynamically import _React_ components, which `abcjs` is not.

Comment: @juliomalves do you know how to import non-react client side libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`next/dynamic` is used to dynamically import *React* components.

To dynamically import regular JavaScript libraries you can simply use [ES2020 dynamic `import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import).

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Music({ note }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const abcjsInit = async () => {
            const abcjs = await import("abcjs");
            abcjs.renderAbc("paper", "X:1\nK:D\nDDAA|BBA2|\n")
        };
        abcjsInit();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="paper"></div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this actually create a separate chunk file?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK Yes, this will create a separate chunk for `abcjs`, that will be loaded separately.