# Nextjs dynamic import of multiple exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using a third party package which im loading using next js dynamic:

```
const am5 = dynamic(() => import("@amcharts/amcharts5"), {ssr: false})
```

The amcharts5 that it's importing is a bunch of exports and imports

```
export { Root } from "./.internal/core/Root";
export { Theme } from "./.internal/core/Theme";
export { addLicense, registry, disposeAllRootElements } from "./.internal/core/Registry";
export { ready } from "./.internal/core/util/Utils";
...several other lines and some imports too
```

However when I run dev/build my application is falling over due to this line below.

```
let root = am5.Root.new('chart')
```

The error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'new')
```

I assume I need to somehow import the Root dynamically too ? I've tried the following already but it didn't work.

```
const { Root }= dynamic(() =>
    import('@amcharts/amcharts5').then((mod) => mod),{ssr:false}
)
```

And also

```
const Root = dynamic(() =>
    import('@amcharts/amcharts5').then((mod) => mod.Root),{ssr:false}
)
```

For reference the package documents importing like this (though i need to dynamically import this)

```
import * as am5 from "@amcharts/amcharts5"
```

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically import abcjs in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67402056/dynamically-import-abcjs-in-next-js)

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**: Next `dynamic(() => ...)` imports can *only* be used to import React components *not* third-party modules. Instead, you should use a regular old [dynamic `import(...)`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import).

**The longer version**:

This is confusing (for me at least) as the docs don't outright state that you *can't* import modules with `dynamic(...)`, only that it should be used to import components:

> React components can also be imported using dynamic imports, but in this case, we use it in conjunction with `next/dynamic` to make sure it works just like any other React Component.

And indeed, looking at [this comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13417#discussioncomment-18924) from a Next maintainer you can't use `dynamic(...)` to import modules, only components.

So here's a somewhat general solution noting that you may need to modify based on how and where you're using the module in your app:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const am5 = await import("@amcharts/amcharts5");
      am5.Root.new("chart");
    })();
  }, []);
```

Perhaps also handy is the [Next docs on dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)

Comment: Does this actually build a separate chunk file?