# TypeError: ... is not a function when using dynamic import

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, next.js, dynamic-import

I'm trying to import [@toolz/use-synchronous-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@toolz/use-synchronous-state) module into my Next.js page. (using next/dynamic):

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
export default function index() {
  const useSynchronousState = dynamic(() => import("@toolz/use-synchronous-state").then(m => m.useSynchronousState));
  const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useSynchronousState(null);
  return(.......);
}
```

But it returns a runtime error.

```
TypeError: useSynchronousState is not a function
```

I also tried regular import but it returns the same error:

```
const useSynchronousState = import("@toolz/use-synchronous-state");
```

Comment: `next/dynamic` is used to dynamically import React components. For regular JavaScript modules/functions just use [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67402056/dynamically-import-abcjs-in-next-js.

Comment: @juliomalves this also returns the same error `const useSynchronousState = import("@toolz/use-synchronous-state");` or I wrote it wrong?

Comment: `import(...)` returns a promise that you will have to handle accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a React component, you need to import it without using next/dynamic, like this: `(await import(__PATH__)).default`